# golang thread count misleading

Tags: multithreading, go

I have written a small application on go, which starts 4 threads for doing various things + one main thread. So in total there are 5 threads. But if I'll start activity monitor and monitor the process, this is what I see

[image]

First of all why 7 threads. And it is not constant. Sometimes it is 5 and other times it is 7. Also all 4 threads started by main thread ends after doing hat they are suppose to. I verify that threads end by putting a differ statement on the top of thread. Still thread count in Activity monitor stays 7.

Does anyone knows what is going on over here? Are these extra threads started by go runtime? Is there a way to find out how many threads are active my program that are started by my code and not by go runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes they are started by the runtime, for example http://play.golang.org/p/c0cIngo_sO it will print 4 goroutines are running.

Goroutines aren't threads, 1 OS thread can handle 100s of goroutines, however if you're doing something heavy or using a blocking system call, the runtime will start a new thread to handle the other goroutines.

Comment: So go runtime will start new OS threads and move goroutine to that thread on its own if there is a need. And I do not need to call GOMAXPROCS for runtime to spawn new threads if needed.

Comment: `GOMAXPROCS` assigns os threads to physical processors as far as I know, so it is still a good idea to do so, otherwise all your goroutines might run on one processor core.

Comment: While doing dome reading online I found this -> "The runtime starts out with several G’s. One is in charge of garbage collection, another is in charge of scheduling, and one represents the user’s Go code. Initially, one M is cre- ated to kick off the runtime. As the program progresses, more G’s may be created by the user’s Go program, and more M’s may become necessary to run all the G’s. As this happens, the runtime may provision additional threads up to GOMAXPROCS. Hence at any given time, there are at most GOMAXPROCS active M’s." So it seems OS threads will be created on its own if neded.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you mean Goroutines when you say threads.

The Go runtime transparently multiplexes lightweight Goroutines onto OS threads. That's also why you don't need to call functions like `select()`—that's the runtime's job.

If you spawn 7 Go routines and some of them block, the runtime might decide to terminate the idle OS threads. This is why you see less threads than Go routines.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mistake Goroutines for thread.

In your go program, the thread you mean is actually goroutine ，which is a coroutine and is not a real thread , which is implemented by go's runtime(you need to know about go runtime, every go program is running on a runtime, and runtime actually use thread to implement goroutines).Diffrent goroutine may be running in the same thread, or may be not ,but you never know . You can use runtime.GOMAXPROCS  for multi-core cpu .

And the threads you see  in the monitor are real threads .